# RDSTK geocode street2coordinates error

Tags: r, data-science

I am trying to use `RDSTK` to geocode locations.  I am getting this error when trying to geocode the Sears Tower:

```
library(RDSTK)
library(rjson)
street2coordinates("233 S Wacker Dr, Chicago, IL 60606")
```

> Error in fromJSON(get.addy) : unexpected character '<'*

I am ignorant about most things JSON so I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Please add minimum example to reproduce this error in R code.

Comment: I wasnt able to reproduce your error... and the error you're getting doesnt seem to match the code you're running. Are you sure what you've posted above is your actual workflow?